# Black foliage after building lighting in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: unreal-engine4

Black foliage after building lighting.I have downloaded trees asset from Unreal Marketplace and used it in my project using Foliage tool.But the problem is after building the lights the foliage becomes black.How to solve this problem.[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a lightmap issue.

You can either:
A) In your StaticMesh window set LightMap coordinate index to 1 and LightMap resolution to 64. If it already is set and mesh is still too dark, and in case of trees it most likely will be, you should:

B) Just set that mesh to "Stationary".